# Is there a shortcut to insert a proper apostrophe in a flash text field?

Tags: flash, text, fonts

When I type into a text-field in flash, an apostrophe will display as this: **'**

But when I type into fireworks, word and more, I get the proper **’** apostrophe. Is there keyboard shortcut too insert the latter? As of current I need to copy and paste this from word to Flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "proper" rich apostrophe is rich-text formatting and will need to be programmed into your Flash application. WYSIWYG inputs will automatically parse an apostrophe replacing it with the nice ’ that you want to get.

If you are inputting this in a Flash development environment then no shortcut exists for what you want. However, you can modify the keyboard shortcut set by following Adobe's instructions: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/10.0_UsingFlash/WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7f90a.html

If you are looking at inserting a "rich" apostrophe into a Flash application WYSIWYG or text area then you'll need to program it for shortcuts and/or choose one that is preprogrammed. You can find WYSIWYG libraries like this one http://www.flashtexteditor.com/ for download.

Comment: Ah, not the answer I was hoping for but a good resource for getting close. Thanks.